# Two differential equations with constants

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the solutions of the following equations:

$$\ddot{x}=-g+\alpha\dot{x}$$

and 
$$\ddot{x}=-g+\alpha\dot{x}^2$$

Considering $g$ and $\alpha$ as constants. I have no idea of how to start, my intuition is that I need to have a term like $\ddot{x}\dot{x}$ somewhere but I can't figure out how and I must to use basic calculus from there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Substitute $x'=z$ for both equations. Then it's separable and easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Both equations are first order separable on $\dot{x}$. In the first one, take $y=\dot{x}$, and you get $y'=-g+\alpha y$, or 
$$
\frac{y'}{-g+\alpha y}=1. 
$$
After integrating you get 
$$
\ln(-g+\alpha y)=t+c. 
$$
Taking exponential and letting $k=e^c$, you get $y(t)=\frac{g+ke^t}\alpha$. As this is $\dot x$, finally you get 
$$
x(t)=\frac{d+gt+ke^t}\alpha
$$

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the nonlinear one, making $u = \dot x$

$$
\dot u = \alpha u^2-g\Rightarrow \dot u = g\left(\frac{\alpha}{g}u^2 - 1\right)
$$

and now making $v = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{g}}u$ we have

$$
\sqrt{\frac{g}{\alpha}}\dot v = g(v^2-1)
$$

or

$$
\frac{dv}{v^2-1} = \sqrt{\alpha g}dt\Rightarrow -\tanh^{-1}(v) = t\sqrt{\alpha g} - C_0\Rightarrow v = \tanh\left(C_0-t\sqrt{\alpha g}\right)
$$

or

$$
\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{g}}\dot x = \tanh\left(C_0-t\sqrt{\alpha g}\right)
$$

and finally

$$
x = C_1-\frac{\ln \left(\cosh \left(t \sqrt{\alpha  g}-C_0\right)\right)}{\alpha }
$$